# Не устонавливливается модуль pyOpenSSL в QPython3 v 3.6.6

Tags: python-3.6

Я не могу работать с сайтами через QPython3 т. к. не устонавливливается модуль pyOpenSSL
Сам код:

```
import requests 

s=requests.get('https://yandex.ru/pogoda/golovchino')
s=open(u'(Путь к файлу) pogoda.txt', 'w')
```

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Убедитесь, что у Вас не установлен python другой версии кроме той, которую предполагается использовать для выполнения этого скрипта
2. Выполните `pip install pyopenssl` или `pip install --upgrade pyopenssl`, чтобы установить или обновить Ваш openssl для python соответственно.
3. Попробуйте обновить `requests`: `pip install --upgrade requests`, возможно, используется неподдерживаемая старая версия

Comment: 1. Та же самая версия что нужна для работы скрипта 2. Ошибка (картинка вверху) 3. Обновил, все равно ошибка

Comment: @XDavidosX Тогда просто `pip install openssl`

Comment: Увы, пробовал (вверху картинки)

Comment: @XDavidosX Извините, ошибся: `pip install pyopenssl` должно работать.

Comment: Ничего страшно, всё равно не работает) (картинка вверху, самая последняя)

Comment: @XDavidosX Что именно не работает? Не устанавливается openssl? В какой момент возникла указанная на последней картинке ошибка?

Comment: не устанавливается/не работает pyOpenSSL, возникла в момент установки, скачалось но не установилось